# Spreading text to match the parent width

Tags: java, android, user-interface, textview

Please have a look at the following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SalesInqury" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/sales_inqury"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/add_2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:ems="8" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This generates the following output

[image]

To be honest, this is not what I want. The text should "spread" to match the screen width, until it find the image view. I think improving the space between letters might be the solution.

But I would like to know whether there is any better solution, which we can do in Code or XML.

Comment: you are Using Wrap_content that will acquire the area according to its size 
other than this Match parent/fill parent can favor you more friendly

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want the EditText below "Sales Inquiry".

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SalesInqury" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/add_2"
        android:text="@string/sales_inqury"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:ems="8" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note I replaced the ImageView with drawableRight. It is called compoundDrawable and it could be set to any location near the text of TextView.
There is no need to use RelativeLayout here. Vertical LinearLayout should do the trick.

```
layout_width="match_parent"
```

Tells that the View should be spread across the width of the layout.

But if you want EditText in the same line as "Sales Inquiry" then it's done line this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".SalesInqury" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/add_2"
        android:text="@string/sales_inqury"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:ems="8" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use horizontal LinearLayout, set layout_width of first TextView to wrap_content.
The EditText should use layout_weight="1" (only works in LinearLayout) that means it will take as much space available. When using layout_weight in horizontal LinearLayout, set the layout_width to 0dp. If it's vertical LinearLayout, layout_height should be 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i did some changes in your code. I use LinerLayout instead of Relative Layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3.0f"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0f"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0f"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0f"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:ems="8" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should have replaced the ImageView with compound drawable. Also. I wonder if that's what he wanted. I thought he wants the EditText below "Sales Inquiry". Also, if you use layout_weight in horizontal LinearLayout, you should set layout_width="0dp"